# URL-Rewrite to One site But not the Other

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

We have our own domain and have several subdomains.  One of the sites needs to be accessed *only* via SSL, but people are allowed to type http and still arrive there.  The URL-Rewrite forces the http into https.

So my two subdomains are:  `sub1.domain.org` and `sub2.domain.org`.

Thus, if I type

`http://sub1.domain.org/page_on_domain1`

it is rewritten to

`https://sub1.domain.org/page_on_domain1`

-which is correct.  But if I do this (which is not possible - `page_on_domain1` does not exist on `sub2.domain.org`:

`https://sub2.domain.org/page_on_domain1`

My url-rewrite rule seems to work properly, but I want that last address to give me an error page instead, since the page doesn't exist on that subdomain.

I am testing this in Firefox on Windows 7 x64 Pro.

My url-rewrite rule is as follows (I am doing it through the IIS7 GUI):

```
Requested URL:  Matches the Pattern:  (*)  Using Regular Expressions (ignore case)
Conditions:  Match All:  Input:  {HTTPS}  Matches the Pattern:  ^Off$
Redirect URL:  https://sub1.domain.org/{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now, I've tried changing the Requested URL Pattern to: `.*sub1.domain.org/.*` but the regex tester in IIS7 says it doesn't match against `https://sub1.domain.org`  - I don't understand that.

How can I keep the rewrite of http to https for sub1.domain.org, but not have any effect at all on sub2.domain.org ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config for the particular site that I want to be accessed via `https`, and to have `http` rewritten to `http`, I set this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```